# HTML Canvas wrongly merging images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So i have this problem that goes like:

- I create a canvas and set BG using CSS.
- I than draw a grid on the Canvas.
- I then use a function to loop through an array and depending on what is found, i load .PNGs and bind an onload drawImage function to them.

Basicly, im drawing more than one image on a canvas. But instead of following the parameters (X, Y), it somehow "merges" all (if 2 or more) PNGs and draws them the X/Y of the most recent drawn one.

```
    this.drawShips = function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++){
        var ship = participants[i];
        var loc = ship.location;
        var img;

        var offsetX = -20;
        var offsetY = -20;

        if (ship.name == "Hyperion"){
            var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(img, loc[0] + offsetX, loc[1] + offsetY);
                }
                img.src = "hyperion.png";
                console.log("draw: " + ship.name + " @ " + loc);
                // continue doesnt help
        }
        if (ship.name == "Primus"){
            var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(img, loc[0] + offsetX, loc[1] + offsetY);
                }
                img.src = "primus.png";
                console.log("draw: " + ship.name + " @ " + loc);
        }
        if (ship.name == "Sharlin"){
            var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(img, loc[0] + offsetX, loc[1] + offsetY);
                }
                img.src = "sharlin.png";
                console.log("draw: " + ship.name + " @ " + loc);
        }
    }
}
```